# Why do I get mail when I unplug my adapter?

Tags: udev, power-management, mailx

Usually I only get the terminal output `You have new mail in /var/mail/$USER` after running certain upgrades but I've started getting it every couple days after running other commands, seemingly at random. The new mail in `/var/mail/$USER` is always to akin to this:

```
Message-Id: <E1YHfKT-0008LI-2d@debianator>
From: root <root@debianator>
Date: Sat, 31 Jan 2015 22:11:45 +0100

Adapter 0: off-line
```

Note that it doesn't happen every time i plug put the AC adapter.

I use a simple bash script (run by udev) to hibernate when battery is low and the AC adapter isn't connected. The script uses `acpi` to detect the latter and has been working for years without mailing me.

So what service could be mailing `Adapter 0: off-line` to me?

**EDIT:**

Below is the script I use to hibernate on low battery. On further inspection, I definitely think it's related. Note the `if acpi -a | grep 'off-line'` lines. When I run `acpi -a | grep 'off-line` I get the output `Adapter 0: off-line`. That is the exact output that is send to my mail - so how do I stop it?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Critical battery level (acpi reports it at 5%)
CRITICAL=6

battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -o [0-9]*% | sed s/%//`
if [ ! $battery_level ]
then
   exit
fi
if [ $battery_level -le $CRITICAL ]
then
   if acpi -a | grep 'off-line'
   then
      # Warning
      sudo -u andreas DISPLAY=":0.0" notify-send -u critical "Gimme power"
      sleep 60s
         if acpi -a | grep 'off-line'
         then

            sudo -u andreas DISPLAY=":0.0" notify-send -u critical "Shutting down"
            sleep 2s
            /bin/systemctl hibernate
         fi
   fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds *like* when a cronjob creates output, and it gets mailed to you.

I have no idea why this output is being mailed to you.  But if you think it's from the script, maybe you could suppress the output:

```
-   if acpi -a | grep 'off-line'
+   if acpi -a | grep 'off-line' >/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't it be `... > /dev/null` (with space)?

Comment: either should work

Comment: OK. I have edited script now. Will know if it works when computer powers out (38% left). BTW: I just noticed that I'm using a trigger script (for some forgotten reason related to udev) to launch above script like this: `batterylow.sh | at now`. That could probably explain the cronjob-like behavior!

Comment: maybe because of udev timeouts; you're not supposed to run stuff directly from udev if it's going to e.g. sleep for 60 seconds.

Comment: Yep, that's it! That the reason why it would only work with the trigger script. Your solution to suppress the output works. Thanks!